# Memory consuming when upload file to server

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I explored memory leaking problem with my ASP .NET app when uploading files to server. For this purpose I wrote a very easy controller with two methods:

```cs
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class MoqController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost()]
    [Route("UploadString")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> UploadStringAsync(string str)
    {
        return Ok(str);
    }

    [HttpPost()]
    [Route("UploadFile")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFileAsync(IFormFile uploadedFile)
    {
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

Invoking the `UploadFileAsync` method via Swagger increases the memory used by the application, and the garbage collector does not clear it. Memory consumption increases by 1-3 megabytes for each query and is weakly dependent on file size.

Calling the `UploadStringAsync` method does not seem to lead to this behavior

What is the reason of such behavior and how it might be changed?

Comment: The file is probably larger than 85,000 bytes, and therefore falls into the Large Object Heap. Accordingly, the garbage collector will not touch it when clearing the zero generation, but will delete it only after a full garbage collection.

Comment: Maybe you can refer to this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32017300/asp-net-mvc-web-api-file-upload-memory-not-being-deallocated-after-upload) in SO.